# How to display fibonacci sequences less than upper bound (CLISP)

Tags: recursion, lisp, common-lisp, fibonacci, clisp

I am trying to display a Fibonacci sequence less than an upper bound, but I'm having trouble printing out the series that is constrained by that upper bound.

Without using imperative programming principles with declaring variables such as setf, setq, and set, etc. How can I solve this problem?

So far I have

```
(defun fibonacci (n &optional (a 0) (b 1))
  (if (or (zerop n) (< a n)
      nil)
      (cons a (fibonacci (1- n) b (+ a b)))))
```

Expected output of `(fibonacci 100)`: `(0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89)`. However, what I am getting is `(0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55)`.

Answer (score 3):

What you meant is

```
(defun fibonacci (n &optional (a 0) (b 1))
  (if (or (zerop n) (> a n))
      nil
      (cons a (fibonacci n b (+ a b)))))
```

You had a `)` placement typo / error, and the flipped test. Also, `n` is the upper limit, not a *count*. So there's no reason to decrease it.

Comment: You're right. That works for (fibonacci 100), but I think the test is wrong. For example, fibonacci(10) will return (0 1 1 2 3) when it should return (0 1 1 2 3 5 8)

Comment: I've fixed another error that you had. `n` is the upper limit, not a _count_. so there's no reason to decrease it.

Answer (score 3):

You are decreasing upper bound for no reason. When you remove `1-` and move one `)` to right place, it works as expected:

```
(defun fibonacci (n &optional (a 0) (b 1))
  (if (or (zerop n) (> a n))
      nil
      (cons a (fibonacci n b (+ a b)))))
```

Tests:

```
CL-USER 4 > (fibonacci 10)
(0 1 1 2 3 5 8)

CL-USER 5 > (fibonacci 100)
(0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89)
```

Comment: they had `(< a n)`. Fibonacci numbers grow so fast, even with the `1-` bug it worked correctly for all but a few small `n` (evidently :) ).